# How to add classes to comments?

Tags: comments, theming

I've put the following code above `print render($content['comments']);` in `comment-wrapper.tpl.php` of our theme to add `question` or `answer` class to every comment:

```
    foreach($content['comments'] as &$c) {
      if(is_array($c) && array_key_exists('#entity_type', $c) && $c['#entity_type'] == 'comment') {
        $uid = $c['comment_body']['#object']->uid;
        $c['#attributes']['class'][] = $uid == 1 ? 'answer' : 'question';
      }
    }
```

The generated HTML however has no `question` or `answer` classes. Please help me to correct the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code worked for me, put it in your theme's template.php and replace `theme` with the name of your theme:

```
function theme_preprocess_comment(&$vars) {
  $element = $vars['elements'];
  $comment = $element['#comment'];

  if(array_key_exists('#entity_type', $element) && $element['#entity_type'] == 'comment') {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = $comment->uid == 1 ? 'answer' : 'question';
  }
}
```

Although I think the extra checks for entity type is not necessary since this theme is only applied to comments.

Answer (score 1):

I think your [ternary statement](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) is off in that code.

I would also suggest an alternative approach.  You can use `hook_preprocess_comment()` in a template.php file or in a custom module.  With this you can hook into the comment before it's rendered to the page, run each comment through an logic test and add a class to the entire comment, or add an html chunk before or after the comment's html.  See more on [hook_preprocess](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess/7) and [render arrays](http://drupal.org/node/930760).

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with that ternary statement, it translates to `if ($uid == 1) { $c['#attributes']['class'][] = 'answer'; } else { $c['#attributes']['class'][] = 'question'; }`. Could you expand on what you mean by that?

Comment: Okay fair enough. It looked off to me because I'm used to seeing parentheses around the first expression.